# What is the cleanest approach handling many to many relationships?

Tags: c#

A little background on this question as I know most commonly using an assignment/junction table will address this...

I'm working on a C# MVC web application, and I have classes a through f. class a is a base class for classes b through g all have multiple properties in common. My issue lies in classes b and c have a many to many relation ship as well as b/d, e/c, and f/d.

I've looked through inheritance models, but I've not really found an example where subclasses have many to many relationships or how best to address them.

It looks like my options are either:
A) Table/Class A as my base, with tables for the assignments b/c, b/d, e/c, and f/d
or
B)Throw the Base out the window and have tables b, c, d, e, f and still have the tables for the assignments b/c, b/d, e/c, and f/d

My question is am I missing an option, is there a preferred direction on this?

UPDATE:  I'm looking for the best approach in both the DB and the application structure. Does the underlying table structure need to follow option A or B. I'm sorry if this question seems silly, but I've been beating my head on this one.

Comment: I would start by designing the database tables and make sure you determine the Primary Keys of the database.  The primary keys will be he links between the classes.  Remember when you have a primary key you can have only one items with the key.  So with a students database you will have one table with the student ID (Primary Key) and Name.  Then you will have a list of courses with the courses have an ID (a course may be taught at more once) and name.  And then you have the Classes (each with an ID) taught in a room and a time.  Finally you have a table with student ID and Classes.

Comment: So option B. I was thinking that would be the case, but was kind of hoping that since all of the tables I'm considering share properties name, spec_code, start and end dates, that there might be a better option than repeating those 5 times

Comment: You can create a property table with ID (primary key), properties name, spec_code, start and end dates.  Then you can reference the ID in the other tables.

Answer (score 1):

Why *Inheritance* ... rather you should be using *Composition* here. I mean your class b should be composed with class c instance as class member. something like

```
public class B
{
  public IEnumerable<C> ListOfC { get; set; }
}
```